# Using a variable derived from a drop-down list as the column name in a select statement ... Access DB

Tags: sql, database, select, vbscript

I'm working with the world's worst DB that was already here so don't blame me for that.

So, here's what I have so far ...

```
module = txtModule.value
presstype = txtPressType.value

SQL_query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_spareparts WHERE '"& module &"' <> '""' AND '"& module &"' = '"& presstype &"' AND Manufacturer = '"& txtsrch.value &"' ORDER BY SAP_Part_No"
Set rsData = conn.Execute(SQL_query)
```

This brings up the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_spareparts WHERE 'Banyan_Module' <> '"' AND 'Banyan_Module' = 'PB' AND Manufacturer = 'Tester' ORDER BY SAP_Part_No
```

Is there any way I can use the module variable as a column name - obviously the ''s around the column name are causing an error. This is really bothering me.

BTW, I'm writing this in VBScript inside a .HTA application page as it has to run locally on tech PCs.

Thanks.

R.

Comment: "I'm working with the world's worst DB that was already here"... aren't we all?

Comment: You should change the `'"& module &"' <> '""'` for `LEN('"& module &"') > 0`, or `'"& module &"' <> ''`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the variables you are using are intended to be column names you don't need the quotes around them

```
SQL_query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_spareparts WHERE "& module &" <> '' AND "& module &" = "& presstype &" AND Manufacturer = '"& txtsrch.value &"' ORDER BY SAP_Part_No"
```